# $e^{-}(p_1)+e^{+}(p_2) \longrightarrow H(k_1) + Z(k_2)$ propagator approximation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, scattering, propagator, electroweak

I'm considering the scattering: 
$$e^{-}(p_1)+e^{+}(p_2) \longrightarrow H(k_1) + Z(k_2)$$
                                                      [image]

Calculating the Feynman amplitude: 
$$\mathcal{M}=i\frac{2m_Z^2}{v}\varepsilon^*_{\nu}(k_2)\frac{i\left(g^{\mu\nu}-\frac{q^{\mu}q^{\nu}}{m^2_Z}\right)}{q^2-m^2_Z}\frac{ig}{4\cos \theta_W}\bar{v}(p_2)\gamma_{\mu}(V-A\gamma_5)u(p_1) $$
Since $m^2_Z \gg m_e^2$, we can neglect $q^{\mu}q^{\nu}$

Usually in the t-channel diagrams of the EW one consider the approximation $q << M_z \,\, or \,\, M_w $ 
                         [image]

> 1) I don't fully understand why $\lim_{m_z \gg m_e} D^{\mu\nu}(q) \simeq \frac{-ig^{\mu\nu}}{q^2-m_z^2}$
>
> 2) Is it true for all s-channel EW diagram with masses in the intial state $\ll$$M_z$ or $M_w$

Comment: Could you please check your expressions? Is everything ok with the first expression for amplitude?

Comment: I think so, apart from a minus sign that I thank you for letting me find. What is your doubt?

Comment: I think the real approximation being made here is $q<< M_z$. When you make this explicit, its easy to see why the propagator is merely $\frac{ i g_{\alpha \beta}}{M_w^2} $. It so happens that in most experimental situations $s \sim q \sim m_e$

Comment: @Anonjohn , it seems that Stefano means that we neglect $q^{\mu}q^{\nu}$ term in numerator but holds $q^2$ term in denominator.